# Imagemagick not working after installation on windows

Tags: php, imagemagick

I was developing a website of image editing tools in CodeIgniter. ImageMagick can perform all the image editing operations, so I need the software configuration done with PHP Xamp. I have installed ImageMagick php extension on Windows.

My specifications are:

- Windows 64 bit
- Xamp: 32 bit
- PHP version 7.2.1
- ImageMagick exe: ImageMagick-7.0.8-7-Q16-x86-dll.exe
- ImageMagick dll library: php_imagick-3.4.3-7.1-ts-vc14-x86

And I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fh0YJl1dUs8) tutorial FOR installation. But the Imagemagick extensions didn't appear in the PHP extension library.

I know I can make my app using JavaScript, but I have to accomplish this task in PHP.

php.ini Dynamic Libraries

```
extension=bz2
extension=curl
extension=fileinfo 
extension=gd2
extension=gettext
extension=imagick
;extension=gmp
;extension=intl
;extension=imap
;extension=interbase
;extension=ldap
extension=mbstring
extension=exif      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=mysqli
;extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=openssl
;extension=pdo_firebird
extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci
;extension=pdo_odbc
;extension=pdo_pgsql
extension=pdo_sqlite
;extension=pgsql
;extension=shmop
```

Comment: What have you tried to enable Imagemagick? Have you installed everything, enabled the extension, and restarted the webserver?

Comment: yes done everything.

Comment: Is there anything written to an error log? Are you sure you have edited the proper `php.ini` (there are seperate ones for webserver and CLI)?

Comment: Imagemagick does not have any php extensions; it s an external program called using exec(). Are you talking about Imagick which is a php API?

Comment: Imagick is API of ImageMagic, we need ImageMagick to work imagick, am I right?

Comment: @NicoHaase I have added php.ini dynamic library part of the code.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved:

I installed ImageMagick-7.0.8-5-Q8-x64-dll.exe and everything works fine. Thank God.